# If <option> is selected deactivate one or more <option> in another dropdown

Tags: javascript

I am honest, I'm not a Javascript expert. What I want to achieve is to deactivate one or more `<option>` in the Second Dropdown based on the selection in the First Dropdown

I checked a lot of other answer here but I was not able to adapt them to my code.

```
<select name="ptp_filter_doc_category" data-column="doc_category" data-tax="doc_category" data-search-column="doc_category_hfilter" aria-label="Category">
  <option value="">Category</option>
  <option value="category-one">Category 1</option>
  <option value="category-two">Category 2</option>
</select>

<select name="ptp_filter_tag_one" data-column="tag_one" data-tax="tag_one" data-search-column="tag_one_hfilter" aria-label="Tag 1">
  <option value="">Tag</option>
    <option value="tag-1">Tag 1</option>
    <option value="tag-2">Tag 2</option>
    <option value="tag-3">Tag 3</option>
    <option value="tag-4">Tag 4</option>
    <option value="tag-5">Tag 5</option>
    <option value="tag-6">Tag 6</option>
 </select>
```

What I want to achieve is:

if Category 1 is selected -> Tag 3, Tag 4, Tag 5, Tag 6 are deactivated

I tried this:

```
if ($('option[value=category-1]').prop('selected', true)) {
  $('option[value=tag-3]').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: Please note that both categories are named `category-one`. If you use that name, you won't see changes when you switch categories.

Comment: @Arjan just corrected ;)

Comment: @esqew I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code will not work because the filtering checks for the wrong value. It should be:

```js
if ($('option[value=category-one]').prop('selected', true)) {
  $('option[value=tag-3]').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

And you may want to use data tags in the tag options to specify for which categories they should be enabled/disabled, so the link between category and tag is not as fixed.